# Datatables Editor pagingType not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-datatables-editor

Here is all the code related to the #results table:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function) {
editor = new jQuery.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "<?php echo $full_dir . '/ajax_call.php'; ?>",
    table: "#results",
    fields: [ {
            label: "Mfg ID",
            name:  "ball_mfg.mfgID"
        }, {
            label: "Mfg name:",
            name:  "ball_mfg.name"
        }, {
            label: "Model #",
            name:  "ball_model.modelID"
        }, {
            label: "Model Name:",
            name:  "ball_model.name"
        }
    ]
} );

jQuery('#results').DataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: {
        url: "<?php echo $full_dir . '/ajax_call.php'; ?>",
        type: 'POST'
    },
    columns: [
        { "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<input type="radio" name="select_model" class="radio1 my_input" data-modelID="'+full.ball_model.modelID+'">';
        }},  // here's a radio button, modify to use data to populate it,
        { data: "ball_mfg.name" },
        { data: "ball_model.name" }
    ],
    select: false,
    buttons: [
    ]
} );
```

This only displays the standard Previous, page numbers and Next button.   You can view the output at https://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/bowling-resources/bowling-ball-information

My preference would actually be to have an input box.   You'll note that I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/pagination/input.js"></script>
```

in the header and I've tried to use 
    "pagingType":"input",

as well but it doesn't seem to matter which paging Type that I use, it simply does not change the pagination buttons.

I'm using DataTables Editor to generate this because it needs to be run on the server side (due to returned results) and so I can display only a few tables (which are joined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgm8i.png) that loads. There is no `"pagingType"`. Change it to `input` so we can see the output when it is written correctly.

Comment: I was working on 2 pages at once and making changes to the wrong page.   So when you noted that, I found that mistake out.  Thanks !!